# iOS: the executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, ipa, entitlements

So I've inherited development work for another users iOS application, and am doing my best to be able to make a working IPA file for it.  I've been trying for the better part of 7 hours fighting with provisioning profiles, Entitlements errors, etc trying to get my .ipa file to install correctly, but have yet to do so.  Recently I was able to get the application on my physical device by just pressing run and allowing it to deploy that way (this means that the provisioning profile and the device are all set up to work for the application, right?).  Whenever I build the archive file and and distribute it as an .ipa file and try to install this .ipa through either itunes or the Iphone Configuration Utility, however, I continue to get the "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements" error.  Is something wrong with my schemes or...?  I think if I can't get it working soon I'm going to reinstall xcode, and clear out all my certificates, devices, provisions and just restart from square one.

This is an older project so it still had an Entitlements.plist file with it, which I've read is now longer used in xcode 4.x.  I've made sure that the filepath for it isn't referenced, but should I just delete it?

I apologize if this issue has come up before, but this seems like an error message that gets spit out for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Make sure you are using provisioning profile that contains your device UDID in it. Open up the provisioning profile in text edit, you will see the UDID were added.

Comment: There are a lot of answers to "invalid entitlements" questions already. Which of those answers have you tried so far? What makes your  question different?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, all my devices have had their UDID's added correctly and I remade all the certificates and provisions, so I'm fairly certain none of that is the problem.  I've done my best to compare what I did to several guides I've found, so I'm posting this trying to see if I forgot something.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue.  Tried adding keys get-task-allow=true and aps-environment=development to the entitlements file (http://www.karlmonaghan.com/2011/07/08/the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements-0xe8008016/), but didn't make a difference.  I created the Ad Hoc profile for this new app, added the device ID's from other apps, but it won't install on the device.

Comment: I also unchecked "Use Entitlements File" in teh target summary tab, under "Entitlements" section, didn't make a difference with the error.  The message dialog appears twice for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using correct provisioning profile(including device UDID), but Build Configuration was set to "Release".

So, after setting to "Build", it works.